# How to fix the WARNING message while running "mvn clean install"

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am using jdk 8 and maven version 3.3.9 to create spring boot application with latest version 1.5.6.RELEASE. I am getting the following Warning messages while running `mvn clean install`

```
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.XXXX:foo:jar:1.0.0
[WARNING] 'parent.relativePath' of POM com.XXX:foo:1.0.0 (/home/user/parent/foo/pom.xml) points at com.XXX:parent instead of org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent, please verify your project structure @ line 12, column 13
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.XXX:bar:jar:1.0.0
[WARNING] 'parent.relativePath' of POM com.XXX:bar:1.0.0 (/home/user/parent/bar/pom.xml) points at com.XXX:parent instead of org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent, please verify your project structure @ line 12, column 13
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
```

My project is a multi-module build. The directory structure is:

```
xxx-project
|-- pom.xml
|-- foo
|   |-- pom.xml
|-- bar
|   |-- pom.xml
```

My foo/pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>foo</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>com.xxx.foo.App</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <lombok.version>1.16.18</lombok.version>
        <log4jdbc.log4j2.version>1.16</log4jdbc.log4j2.version>
        <rest.assured.version>3.0.3</rest.assured.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bgee.log4jdbc-log4j2</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4.1</artifactId>
            <version>${log4jdbc.log4j2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${rest.assured.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-loaded.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The above pom.xml is generated using maven archetype spring-boot-blank project from github.

The parent pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.XXX</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>parent</name>
  <modules>
    <module>foo</module>
    <module>bar</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

How to solve this warning messages while compiling my source code?

Kindly provide your inputs.

Comment: Could You show us how Your pom.xml looks like? Especially line 12 ;)
And maybe Your project structure.

Comment: I have updated my question with pom.xml

Comment: Is the pom.xml you posted the top-level pom in your project?

Comment: No, it is sub module pom.

Comment: I have updated with parent pom.xml. Kindly provide your inputs.

Comment: @SST Although, the question has been answered it might help if you add a description of the directory layout of your project. That would make it more clear that your parent pom is in the parent directory of the modules.

Comment: Thanks @ChristophBöhme!! Can you provide a sample description for this?

Comment: I edited your question and added a paragraph on the directory structure. Can you please check that it is correct?

Comment: Yeah, It's correct. Thanks again @ChristophBöhme

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The problem occurs because Maven by default assumes that the parent pom is found in the parent folder of the one that contains the module pom. However, in your project that does not seem to be the case: Your parent pom is *org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:1.5.6.RELEASE* while the pom *com.xxx:parent:1.0.0* in the parent folder is only used as an aggregator for the modules.

To solve this problem you need to unset the relative path in the parent declaration in the module poms like this:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

Comment: Wonderful explanation! Thanks.

Comment: <relativePath/> - that's what you're adding, for those that skim quickly